# Trouble outputting file size in a text file using powershell command

Tags: command-line, powershell

This is what I am trying to do:

```
createfile until EOF
    $drives = Get-WmiObject win32_volume | ? {{$_.DriveType -eq 3} | % {{Get-PSDrive $_.DriveLetter[0]}
    foreach ($drive in $drives){{
        $path = $drive.root + "*.nsf"
        cmd.exe /C dir /s /b /a /o:gn $path | out-file -append -filepath c:\windows\temp\nsffiles.txt -encoding ASCII
    }

    EOF
```

Somewhere in here, I need to pass the command to catch the file size of the files I'm gathering information on.  It's creating the file without problem, however I'm at a loss on how to add the file size to the string for the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the `cmd.exe dir` call (up to the first pipe) with

`Get-ChildItem -recurse $drive.root -include *.nsf | select directory,name,length`

and pipe that to your out-file.

Get-ChildItem documentation ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx )

Article on Filtering and selecting ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.04.powershell.aspx )